# Overwrite lost focus event to save and display model's lastError

Tags: python, pyqt

How do you overwrite a QWidget's focusOutEvent to save/submit and display the QSqlTablemodel's lastError, after losing focus? I want to inform the user if there was any problems saving the model and have him correct or discard the changes.

I tried implementing the code below on a QWidget, which is a tab in tabControl but it is not executing when I close the tab or when navigating to child/sub tabs

```
def focusOutEvent(self,event):
    print("Losing focus now")
    self.model.submitAll()
    print(self.model.lastError().text())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `focusOutEvent` generally requires the `focusPolicy` to be set to something other than the default of `Qt::NoFocus` in order to receive focus events.

> The policy is `Qt::TabFocus` if the widget accepts keyboard focus by
>   tabbing, `Qt::ClickFocus` if the widget accepts focus by clicking,
>   `Qt::StrongFocus` if it accepts both, and `Qt::NoFocus` (the default) if
>   it does not accept focus at all.

Refer to http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusOutEvent & http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop for more information on this.